# Looking for a children's book about a tiger who travelled the world

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I owned this book in the 1980s in the UK, though I don't recall it being new then. It was a smaller format hardback, maybe 10cm high or so. My recollection of the cover (which could be wrong) is of the anthropomorphic tiger flying a kite, maybe on the great wall of China. It was heavily illustrated but not a picture book.

I recall the plot being him travelling; I do not recall much (if any) peril!

Sorry for the sparse details.

Comment: Was the fact that he was a tiger *fantastical* in this context? Babar, for example, is an elephant but basically just an analogue for a human

Comment: ... was he actually? I mean, Babar's origin story is his mother being killed by a hunter, and the rest of the elephants, as well as the rhinoceri, are animals. Admittedly, I've seen people argue that he's specifically meant to be analogous to African humans, animal up until he learns from Western civilization, and brings that back to his people, uplifting them. Which... kind of makes the books a bit uncomfortable in today's light.

Comment: I would saying being a tiger was not fantastical, but the adventures/travels were

Comment: This question is not about Science Fiction or Fantasy

Comment: What I've found online for the provided book is not fantastic, although admittedly, information is sparse.

Answer (score 3):

Through the method of looking at all the google image search results for children's books with a tiger on them I discovered the book I was looking for is: The Adventures of Little Tiger, by Marielle Sohier and Kathleen N. Daly.

I was wrong about a good number of the details I thought I could remember. The cover:
[image: Adventures of Little Tiger Cover]